# Opening odt from cifs/smb share extremely slow in kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, smb

I have a cifs/smb share mounted in fstab.

With Libreoffice: when attempting to open an *.odt from there it takes a good minute to happen. A *.doc opens instantanously, as does an *.odt from a local drive.

Kubuntu 19.10

Has anyone experienced the same and maybe resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. LibreOffice delay could be dependent on samba share mounting method mounting options.

Create the following files with `sudo` and permission `600`, replacing "your_samba_server_name" with your real samba share server name.

**/etc/systemd/system mnt-test-temp.automount**

```
 [Unit]
 Description=mnt-test-temp
 Requires=network-online.target


 [Automount]
 Where=/mnt/test/temp

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/systemd/system mnt-test-temp.mount**

```
 [Unit]
 Description=mnt-test-temp
 Requires=network-online.target


 [Mount]
 What=//your_samba_server_name/temp
 Where=/mnt/naila/temp
 Options=uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/etc/.share-pw
 Type=cifs


 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/.share-pw**

```
username=<username>
password=<password>
```

Run the following 3 commands in a terminal

```
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo systemctl start mnt-test-temp.automount
 sudo systemctl enable mnt-test-temp.automount
```

You can change mount file names in the /etc/systemd/system directory according your requirements. But take care to follow the naming requiements of files by using the systemd mounting method.